# Is a Python module import at the bottom ok?

Tags: python, flask

Pylint is yelling at me for putting a `from .views import *`at the **end** of my `__init__.py`saying imports should be placed at the top of the module.

If I place it at the top of `__init__.py` then Flask can't find my routes (views) so that doesn't work. Page doesn't load, 404 error. Loads fine when routes are imported at the end.

A couple questions:

- Is Pylint wrong to assume that modules should always go at the top and it's acceptable sometimes to import at the end (like in this case)?
- or is there another way I should be importing my routes?

for reference, in case:

```
.
├── README.md
├── my_app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   └── loggedin.html
│   └── views.py
├── config.py
├── instance
│   └── config.py
├── requirements.txt
└── run.py
```

example of what's in `__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth


app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.config.from_object('config')
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

oauth = OAuth(app)

APP_CALLBACK_URL = app.config['APP_CALLBACK_URL']
APP_CLIENT_ID = app.config['APP_CLIENT_ID']
APP_CLIENT_SECRET = app.config['APP_CLIENT_SECRET']
APP_DOMAIN = app.config['APP_DOMAIN']
APP_BASE_URL = 'https://' + APP_DOMAIN

my_app = oauth.register(
    'MY_APP',
    client_id=APP_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=APP_CLIENT_SECRET,
    api_base_url=APP_BASE_URL,
    access_token_url=APP_BASE_URL + '/oauth/token',
    authorize_url=APP_BASE_URL + '/authorize',
)


from .views import *
```

Comment: Why do you want it in the end? What else is in your `__init__.py`? See also e.g. PEP8

Comment: Without seeing your code we can't answer definitively, but most people manage to write flask apps while still leaving imports at the top of the file where they belong. Can you include an example of your code in the question?

Comment: I do the application setup in `__init__.py` such as creating the Flask instance and setting the default configs, initializing the extensions.

Comment: I've added an example of things in `__init__.py`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, imports should go at the top, but Flask documentation talks about this kind of situations and encourages you to do as you did. Taken from https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/packages/:

> 1. the Flask application object creation has to be in the `__init__.py` file. That way each module can import it safely and the `__name__` variable will resolve to the correct package.
> 2. all the view functions (the ones with a `route()` decorator on top) have to be imported in the `__init__.py` file. Not the object itself, but the module it is in. Import the view module **after the application object is created**.

By the way, don't do `from .views import *`. Do `import .views` instead.

Comment: I think you found it. Scrolling down to the part 'Circular Imports' explains it nicely.

Comment: No. `import .views` does not work. `invalid syntax`. Neither does `import views` -> `No module named views`

Comment: Then maybe `import my_app.views` as the documentation suggests?

Comment: even though I can import the module with `import my_app.views`, the app cannot find the routes. I'm assuming this is because when I `import *` I'm importing the functions into the current namespace rather than references to those functions. Flask can't find the routes if they are prefixed with the module name.

Comment: Then consider the proposed structure used for packages in the provided link (`my_app/my_app/` containing `__init__.py`, `views.py`, etc.), or even better, use a blueprint: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/