# ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from partially initialized module 'market' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I was trying to package my code as it was getting kind of complex for me to keep in one file and i encountered an import error when i tried to run the file that says circular import error, how do i solve this error? I have been analyzing the code and i cannot seem to be able to figure out what might be wrong.

**run.py**

```
from market import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

****init****.**py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from market import routes

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///market.db"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

**routes.py**

```
from market import app
from flask import render_template
from market.models import Item


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/market")
def market():
    items = Item.query.all()
    return render_template("market.html", items=items)
```

**models.py**

```
from market import db


class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(length=30), nullable=False, unique=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    barcode = db.Column(db.String(length=12), nullable=False, unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(length=1024), nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Item {self.name}"
```

**project structure**
[image]

**error**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving your routes import to the bottom of the file should help.

Just as you would do for example with blueprints in application factory. You import blueprints/views after you create app instance with `app = Flask(__name__)`:

```
def create_app(config_filename):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_pyfile(config_filename)

    from yourapplication.model import db
    db.init_app(app)

    
    from yourapplication.views.admin import admin
    from yourapplication.views.frontend import frontend
    app.register_blueprint(admin)
    app.register_blueprint(frontend)

    return app
```

Also check:
[Is a Python module import at the bottom ok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59578249/is-a-python-module-import-at-the-bottom-ok)

Comment: Thank you, this worked. i moved the routes import to the bottom

Answer (score 1):

in your `__init__.py` you import `routes`

in `routes.py` you import `app` (defined in `__init__.py`)

Comment: can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).